# How to display borders in a downloaded word doc file that contains iris data in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard

I want to create a shiny app that downloads some data in a word file. It should have a proper table format with borders like [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DmrEUbjX5DC5CT8AmKl5efV02zxUY48qdqWNYJeDdMI/edit). This is not the same table i am using but what i essentially mean is that it should have **borders** . I created the following shiny app which uses the **iris** datset. It displays the dataset and also downloads it. However the downloaded file does not have **borders**. It looks like this :
[image]

The following is the code which i am using:-

```
library(shiny)

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  (sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel( downloadButton('downloaddata','download table')),#this is the download button
                                                                              
mainPanel(

tableOutput ('table')#this outputs the table
)
  )
  
))


server<- shinyServer(
  
  function(input, output) {
    #1 Dataset l
    l<- reactive({
      iris})#store iris dataset in a reactive variable


    output$table<-renderTable({
      l()})#used to display the iris dataset
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    output$downloaddata<-
      downloadHandler(filename=function()
      {
        paste('Item statistics','doc',sep='.') #uses doc as extension
      }
      ,content=function(file)
      {
        
        (write.table(data.frame(l()),file))
      })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     })
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    } )
    
    shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: `write.table` writes a dataframe to a text file with no formatting. If you want a word document with a nicely formatted table I would suggest to have a look at the `officer` package or output your table as a docx via `rmarkdown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `officer` as @stefan suggested.

```
library(shiny)
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

ui <- fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel( downloadButton('downloaddata','download table')),
        mainPanel(tableOutput('table')))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  l <- reactive({iris})
  
  output$table <- renderTable({l()})
  
  output$downloaddata <- downloadHandler(filename=function() {
      paste('Item statistics','docx',sep='.') #uses doc as extension
    },
    content=function(file) {
      
      ft <- flextable(l()) %>%
        border_outer() %>% 
        border_inner()
      
      doc <- read_docx() %>%
        body_add_flextable(ft)
      
      print(doc, target = file)
    })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
} 

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: This code is not working. It does not download anything.

Comment: @ujjwaltyagi I was missing `magrittr` library.